# Как извлечь переменную из объекта и проверить, является ли он массивом или объектом (JAVA)?

Tags: массивы, json, объекты, mapper

```
{
    "soapenv:eenv": {
        "xmlns:xsd":,
        "soapenv:Body": {
            "queryResponse": {
                "Details": {
                    "xmlns:ns2": "urn:olen",
                    "xsi:type": "ns2:listRawType",
                    "row": [
                        {
                            "item": [
                                {
                                    "xsi:type": "ns2:ItemType_Generic",
                                    "name": {
                                        "xsi:type": "xsd:string",
                                        "content": "CUSTOMER"
                                    },
                                    "value": {
                                        "xsi:type": "xsd:string",
                                        "content": "124124"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "xsi:type": "ns2:ItemType_Generic",
                                    "name": {
                                        "xsi:type": "xsd:string",
                                        "content": "Group"
                                    },
                                    "value": {
                                        "xsi:type": "xsd:string",
                                        "content": "55"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "xsi:type": "ns2:ItemType_Generic",
                                    "name": {
                                        "xsi:type": "xsd:string",
                                        "content": "UNIQUE"
                                    },
                                    "value": {
                                        "xsi:type": "xsd:string",
                                        "content": 456456
                                    }
```

Мне нужно проверить тип объекта "строка" на массив или объект. Если объект «строка» является массивом, просто верните его. если это объект, а не массив, то мы создадим новый список массивов и добавим к нему объект «строка», а затем массив установит массив в объект «Подробности» в качестве замены.

Как мы можем это решить? Спасибо за всех)